# "wordpress theme framework" vs "Blank themes" vs free theme similar to my design?

Tags: css, wordpress, xhtml, wordpress-theming

I got the design (PSD) from client. Which should i choose to make custom Wordpress themes.

- I should use any [Wordpress theme
  Framework](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Frameworks)?
- [or Any WordpressBlank theme?](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Nda&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=wordpress+blank+themes&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=)
- or I should find similar [free theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/)
  to my design then edit to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure without knowing your PSD. It depends.

If the layout from your PSD is too specific, I would go for a blank theme.

If it's a well known 3 column pattern for example that you don't need to create any customization whatsover, I would use a Wordpress Theme Framework.

I would never try to find a free theme and edit it, mainly because:

- you need to read it's licenses and usually attribute properly with a link in your project (bad option when you're doing something for a client);
- usually it's more work to adapt a theme instead of creating from scratch. I would adapt a theme only if 80% of it would be already equal to my PSD requirements.

Comment: thanks for good reply. But "Wordpress theme framework" has something different folder/file structure than blank theme and it needs more learning curve. What are pros and cons to use Theme framework over Blank themes. Mostly i use wordpress as a CMS for site and use blog functionality for one "Blog" page. so basically i create different landing pages and Home page.

Comment: In the scenario you described, I would use a blank theme. It's the best approach IMHO, since you have more control. I like this approach instead of a theme framework because my CSS files are really optimized too.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other comment.  I've used all 3 methods: framework, pre-made, and blank themes, and I've found that using a blank theme is the easiest when starting from a PSD file.  I've used Chris Coyier's blank theme (http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/), which is a bare bones theme with the basic functionality of a WordPress theme, but no CSS styling, making it easier to add your own markup.  I wrote a blog post about this, comparing the differences among blank themes, frameworks, and pre-made themes (http://www.sinawiwebdesign.com/blog/topics/wordpress/use-wordpress-framework-or-blank-theme/).

When I build themes starting from a PSD file, I first write the HTML, CSS, and Javascript code to get a working prototype, and then I convert it to WordPress using a blank theme.  I copy and paste most of my code directly into the blank theme with little modification, then add some code for custom menus, widget areas, support for post thumbnails, etc.